# Using one component with different images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that I want to reference different images with, but I don't want to create a new component specifically for each image. The code I have is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.css'

export default class ColumnComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <img className="" src={imgURL} />
    )
  }
}
```

How can I make it possible to export this one component so that src={imgURL} references different images when it gets used in index.js for example?

Comment: Do you mean you have a list of images from the index.js, for which you want to use ColumnComponent? what do you mean by I want to reference different images

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react';
 import ColumnComponent from './ColumnComponent'
    class Index extends Component {
       state={
         images:[
         {id:'1',img:'www.google.com'},
         {id:'2',img:'www.facebook.com'},
         {id:'3',img:'www.youtube.com'},
            ]
         }
       render(){
        let myImages=this.state.images.map(
              el=>{
                  return <ColumnComponent key={el.id} imgURL={el.img} />})
         return (
           <div>
            {myImages}
           </div>
        )}
    }
       export default Index;
```

In the ColumnComponent please make sure `src={this.props.imgURL}` if you use class component.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are new to React, this is solved by simple prop:

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.css'

export default class ColumnComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <img className="" src={this.props.imgURL} />
    )
  }
}

// Usage
<ColumnComponent imgURL={"http://www.google.it"} />
<ColumnComponent imgURL={"http://www.youtube.com"} />
<ColumnComponent imgURL={"http://www.vk.ru"} />
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does this solve the problem if I want to use ColumnComponent more than once in index.js. Won't imgURL always equal {"http://www.google.it"} ?

Comment: No. I've update the snippet. imgUrl can contain any value, simple string or just a variable.

Comment: Thanks, but how is it known which imgURL should be used in ColumnComponent?

Comment: Why did you created a JS snippet for React?

Comment: @jnoweb depends by how you access to your data. Component remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

you can pass the list of images has **props** to ColumnComponent and use **map** to loop through and create the elements, then use it in **render**.

Then suppose your element (being referenced as el in the below example)  consist of property `image_url`, you can reference the `image_url` property by simply doing `el["image_url"]` in your **img src** component

so that you just need to use **ColumnComponent** only once in **index.js**

**ColumnComponent**

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.css'

export default class ColumnComponent extends React.Component {
 const images = this.props.imgURLs.map(el => {
   return  <img className="" src={el["image_url"]} />
 });  

  render() {
    return (
      {images}
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: i think there is one error here because images is an array, if you do like this chrome will throw you an error. There are two methods you can do to solve that.
First, {images} becomes [images];
Second,{images} becomes <div>{images}</div>

Comment: Edited the post and probably addressed the issue. Waiting for praveen to review/improve upon it.

Comment: Yes @kuchBhi thanks for the edit, i approved the edit.